# Could not locate seesaw/core.clj on classpath?

Tags: java, clojure, classpath, leiningen, seesaw

I'm trying to make a small window using seesaw for Clojure. However, when I attempt to create the JAR file using:

```
lein uberjar
```

I get the following error on the command line for Windows:

```
Caused by: clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.io.FileNotFoundExceptio
n: Could not locate seesaw/core__init.class or seesaw/core.clj on classpath: , 
compiling:(C:\Users\J\Desktop\test\guidemo\project.clj:10:36)
```

Using leiningen, i created a new app and have the following in my project.clj

```
(defproject guidemo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write description"
:url "http://example.com/FIXME"
:license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
        :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
             [seesaw "1.4.4"]]
:main ^:skip-aot guidemo.core
:target-path "target/%s"
:profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})

(ns guidemo.namespace
(:gen-class)
(:require [seesaw.core :as seesaw]))
```

and the following to create a simple window in core.clj (both in my guidemo project)

```
(ns guidemo.core
(:gen-class)
(:require [seesaw.core :as seesaw]))

(def window (seesaw/frame
  :title "First Example"
  :content "hello world"
  :width 200
  :height 50))

(defn -main
  [& args]
(seesaw/show! window))
```

My question is how do I set seesaw/core.clj on my class path? Im pretty new to the scene of leiningen and using seesaw. Most of the examples I've seen answered by daveray pertain to experimenting with the examples inside seesaw. I have no problems running lein operations (lein help, lein compile) on other projects except this one.

Ive downloaded the whole repo of seesaw on daveray's github. Should that be in my guidemo folder? If so where?

Im running leiningen 2.5.0. on Java 1.7.0_67

Thanks for any help guys, Ive been pulling my hair for the last 4 hours setting everything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the following in your "project.clj"

```
(ns guidemo.namespace
(:gen-class)
(:require [seesaw.core :as seesaw]))
```